# no grails command list for netbeans with grails 4

Tags: grails, netbeans

In netbeans, grails adds a right click menu option "Run with grails command".
In previous versions of grails this brought up a dialogue containing a list of  command line actions.
With grails 4, the dialogue is empty.

[image]

Does anyone know where the netbeans plugin was pulling this command list from? 
Using netbeans 8.2 and jdk 1.8+

Comment: [1] Please update your question with your **exact** _NetBeans_ version, _JDK_ version, _Grails_ version and _Groovy and Grails_ plugin version. [2] It looks like you are using NetBeans 8.x, and I thought that its Grails plugin would only work with Grails 3.x. Apart from the issue in your question, are you otherwise using Grails 4 successfully on NetBeans 8.x?

Comment: Otherwise, yes, it works as much as I need it to. It doesn't like breakpoints in some areas. The only other daily complaint is that when formatting a gsp file, the  html formats fine, but any javascript in a script tag gets totally mangled.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know where the netbeans plugin was pulling this command
>   list from?

It will depend on what version of the IDE and what version of the Grails support you are using. 
 https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/0401f3672ee45318c3219ccb266368a5c1199910/contrib/groovy.grailsproject/src/org/netbeans/modules/groovy/grailsproject/commands/GrailsCommandSupport.java#L192 may be what you are looking for.